How to reference/consumme assembly manifest based on CPU in WPF C# Application project?
I want to reference an older Win32 assembly from a Wpf C# application.
I do have both x86 or x64 versions of the Win32 assembly but I don't see how to reference based on selection target CPU.I can only specify either one.
The Visual Studio C# project only seems to allow one reference and I don't see how to reference different version of the assembly based on the selected CPU unless I use an ugly scheme of copying file over each other in a post-build step.
Is it posisble to create a "fat" assembly containing both CPU architecture? I don't recall ever seing that and can't find documentation of example of that. If that exists, what is the syntax and file struture?

If you have a requirement to compile your WPF app as both x86 and x84, you should be able to configure conditional references in the project file: https://setiabud.blogspot.com/2010/10/conditional-reference-in-vs-2010.html

Create an interface, then create and assembly as wrapper for x86 with this interface, then create an assembly for x64. At runtime load type from assembly depend on CPU architecture. Your main project references only interface assembly. Short code:
string assemblyName = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "MyAssembly64" : "MyAssembly32";
IMyWrapper wrapper = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, "MyNamespace.MyWrapper") as IMyWrapper;


I assume these are native libraries called using P/Invoke. That means you do not need  a "reference" to compile your code, you will need to specify all your p/Invoke signatures by hand.
You do need to ensure your dlls are copied to the output directory, but this can simply be done by adding them as files to your project, with "copy to output directory = Copy if Newer".
Next step is to ensure you load the right variant of the dll. In .net 6+  it is possible to use NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver together with NativeLibrary.Load  to load the right file depending on the Environment.Is64BitProcess flag.
With .net 7 P/Invoke source generators it could look something like
// Ensure this is called at startup, for example in a static constructor.
NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), DllImportResolver);
...

[LibraryImport("nativelib",  EntryPoint = "to_lower")]
internal static partial string ToLower(string str);

private static nint DllImportResolver(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath)
{
    if(libraryName != "nativelib") return IntPtr.Zero;
    libraryName = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 
               "nativelib_x64.dll" : 
                "nativelib_x86.dll";
        return NativeLibrary.Load(libraryName , assembly, DllImportSearchPath.AssemblyDirectory)
}

Another alternative would be to just produce a x64 version of your program. By now there should not be that many users unable to run 64-bit software.
